# Using span function to bisect a Map in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a Map of the form [Int, Option[/* of some type that I am using */], thus:

```
scala> val t1: Map[Int,Option[(String,List[Int])]] = Map(500->Some("A",List(1,2,3)))
t1: Map[Int,Option[(String, List[Int])]] = Map(500 -> Some((A,List(1, 2, 3))))

scala> t1 + (400 -> Some("B",List(9,8,7))) + (300 -> None) + (200 -> None)
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Option[(String, List[Int])]] = Map(500 -> Some((A,List(1, 2, 3))), 400 -> Some((B,List(9, 8, 7))), 300 -> None, 200 -> None)
```

Now, I am trying to cleave into two maps, one having all the empty Values -from eponymous **Key/Value** - and the other having none of them, thus:

```
res6.span(e => e._2.isEmpty)
res7: (scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Option[(String, List[Int])]], scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Option[(String, List[Int])]]) = (Map(),Map(500 -> Some((A,List(1, 2, 3))), 400 -> Some((B,List(9, 8, 7))), 300 -> None, 200 -> None))
```

I am failing to understand why I am getting an empty Map on the left, while the < K,**None** > pairs are sitting blissfully inside the Map on the right. They should have been in the Map on the left, or so I expect.

What is the obvious thing that I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `partition` instead of `span`.

> Note: c span p is equivalent to (but possibly more efficient than) (c takeWhile p, c dropWhile p), provided the evaluation of the predicate p does not cause any side-effects.

So, `span` would stop scanning if the condition is not met.

For example,

```
scala> val l = List(1, 9, 8, 0)
scala> l.span(e => e < 2)
res7: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(1),List(9, 8, 0))
scala> l.partition(e => e < 2)
res8: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(1, 0),List(9, 8))
```

Note that, actually for `span`, it might return different results for different runs, unless the underlying collection type is ordered.

In your case, the first element in `map` **may not** `None`. (`Map` is not ordered)

Comment: I missed the critical point of span() _stopping the scan_. Many thanks. @chenzhongpu

Answer (score -1):

By definition when you use `span` we get a `Tuple2` of sequences that are of the same type as the original collection, one contain `true` values and other `false` values.

```
 def span(p: A => Boolean): (Repr, Repr) =
```

In your case

```
res6.span(e => e._2.isEmpty)
```

So in your case you have a `empty` and `non-empty` elements of Tuple2.

If you wish to get `non-empty` values you use simply use `_2` as

```
val nonEmptyValue = res6.span(e => e._2.isEmpty)._2
```

Comment: I don't want to get the non-empty value. I want to separate the empty and non-empty values residing in the map. So, res6.span(e => e._2.isEmpty)._2 doesn't give me what I need. However, thanks for taking time to respond.

Comment: As I mentioned above `if you wish`.